# require("mongojs").connect is undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongojs

I just started to learn mongodb. I tried the following code in my app.js

```
var databaseUrl = "localhost:27017/pixelmargin"; // "username:password@example.com/mydb"
var collections = ["pages"]
var mongojs = require("mongojs");
var db = mongojs.connect(databaseUrl)
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ' error occurs on line 'var db = mongojs.connect(databaseUrl)

Answer (score 9):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs/blob/master/README.md) there is no `.connect()`

You select the db via the following:

```
var mongojs = require("mongojs");
var db = mongojs("dbname");
```

Answer (score 0):

That works for me :

```
var db = require('mongojs').connect('localhost:27017/dbName');
```